A specific inequality involving the Euler totient function.
I am trying to digest the following inequality:
$$
\prod_{p \mid e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p - 1}\right)\sum_{\substack{t \leq \frac{z}{e} \\ (t, e) = 1}} \frac{\mu^{2}(t)}{\phi(t)} \leq \sum_{d \leq z} \frac{\mu^{2}(d)}{\phi(d)}
$$
where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. I am given the following hint: Note that for any squarefree $m$ dividing $e$, we have $\prod_{p \mid m} \frac{1}{p - 1} = \prod_{p \mid m} \frac{1}{\phi(p)}$. Then, using the change of variables $d = tm$, we see that if $t \leq \frac{z}{e}$ and $m \mid e$ then $tm \leq z$.
I understand we are using $\phi(p) = p - 1$ for $p$ prime. I understand that the sum of the LHS is a subset of the sum of the RHS but theres this amplification factor from the product where each product term is slightly greater than 1 and depends on the prime factorisation of e.
I don't understand the hint given in the reasoning specifically why must m be square free and how do we use this to deduce the main inequality.
Can someone provide a clearer explanation for this, thank you. Source: Original Text Here
Edit: So far, I have that
$$
\prod_{p \mid e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p - 1} \right) = \sum_{\substack{m \mid e \\ m \text{ square free}}} \frac{1}{\phi(m)}
$$
simply by expanding out the product. So it follows
$$
\prod_{p \mid e} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p - 1} \right) \sum_{\substack{t \leq \frac{z}{e} \\ (t, e) = 1}} \frac{\mu^{2}(t)}{\phi(t)} = \sum_{\substack{m \mid e \\ m \text{ square free}}} \sum_{\substack{t \leq \frac{z}{e} \\ (t, e) = 1}} \frac{\mu^{2}(t)}{\phi(mt)}
$$
which is by substitution and realising that $m$ and $t$ are coprime using $m \mid e$ and $(t, e) = 1$.
Then using $\mu^{2}(t) \in \{0, 1\}$ and $(m \mid e, et \leq z) \implies mt \leq z$, letting $d := mt$, we have
$$
\sum_{\substack{m \mid e \\ m \text{ square free}}} \sum_{\substack{t \leq \frac{z}{e} \\ (t, e) = 1}} \frac{\mu^{2}(t)}{\phi(mt)} \leq \sum_{d \leq z} \frac{\mu^{2}(d)}{\phi(d)}
$$
also $\mu^{2}(t) \leq \mu^{2}(d)$ because $(m, t) = 1$ and $m$ is squarefree. Is this correct?

Please include all relevant information in the post itself, rather than make volunteer helpers go to some other page and need to extract the information themselves.

That link gives what looks like a good hint.

@martycohen, I have copied the relevant excerpt from the link, including the suggested hint. I'm not understanding why we require m to be squarefree and how we apply the hint to the inequality.

I believe the relevance of the hint is because
$$
\prod_{p\mid e} \biggl( 1 + \frac1{p-1} \biggr) = \sum_{\substack{m\mid e \\ m\text{ squarefree}}}\biggl( \prod_{p\mid m} \frac1{p-1} \biggr).
$$
(Indeed the $1/(p-1)$ can be replaced by any function $f(p)$.) The right-hand side is what we obtain when expanding the left-hand side by multiplying all the binomials out (the generalization of FOIL to an arbritrary number of factors).
The second part of the hint seems to suggest showing that the map $(m,t) \mapsto mt$ is an injective map from $\{m\mid e\} \times \{t\le z/e,\, (t,e)=1\}$ into $\{d\le z\}$.

I think the outer product on the RHS should be a sum, but other than that this answers my question, I've made an edit describing my understanding in full, thank you. Upvoted. (Turns out I can't upvote due to limitations but I have accepted this answer)
